# Summing Only Visible Rows in SSRS 2014 where the visibility condition includes a group aggregate

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have an SSRS report that only shows groups for which the count of values is greater than 1 - the objective is to show records with duplicate email addresses, with details for each record, and a total for all records that have duplicates:

```
email1@test.com
            John Doe
            Jane Doe
        Count: 2
email2@test.com
            James Doe
            Janet Doe
            June Doe
        Count: 3
Total: 5
```

The basic report has a single row group with group expression

```
Group on: [Email]
```

The base recordset also includes records with unique email addresses, but these are filtered out from the report using a group filter with condition

```
CountRows() > 1 = true
```

The problem I have is how to show the correct total count for all records that have duplicates. I understand that report aggregates are not affected by group filters, so simply using Count() for the report total shows the wrong value as it also includes all the single unique records that are filtered out at the group level.

How can I show the correct report total, including only the records for which there are duplicates (i.e. that are visible based on the group filter setting of CountRows() > 1)?

Comment: Looks like you need to use `HAVING` clause. Details here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199.aspx

Comment: I would change the SQL query instead of getting useless rows that you will hide in the report. But it might not be possible in your context.

Comment: Yes - I'm trying to find a solution for report writers that can be implemented with the standard Report Builder tools, including the visual query designer, and that does not require writing any custom queries etc. (The users don't have the skills to do this.) I should have mentioned this in my original post...